# London to Bhubaneswar, India via Budapest and Kiev

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I will be travelling from London to India in Dec 2018 and the trip has layovers in Budapest and Kiev.

1. I will be changing flights in Budapest which requires collecting and re-checking in my baggage. Would I have to leave the transit area for that? I am an Indian citizen with a valid US visa. Would I be requiring a transit visa (or any other visa) for transiting through Budapest? https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/
   According to this site (Case #2), I might not need a transit visa but I want to be sure.
2. Ukraine International Airlines is taking me from Budapest to Kiev and then to New Delhi.(No rechecking of baggage required). I am assuming that I won't require a transit visa for Kiev. Is that a wrong assumption?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: For the Budapest question, see the question [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)  It hinges on whether you have to leave the airside transit area in the Budapest airport.  If Budapest is like most airports, you'll have to leave the transit area, and so you'll need a short-stay visa (Case #3 in your link above, also Case #3 in my link.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would it be possible to remain airside if I didn't have to check-in luggage. I think I can make do with just a cabin bag. I wanted to avoid getting a Schengen visa just for this layover.

Comment: Yes, if you do not need to re-check in baggage, you can remain airside.

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether you need a visa, one of the best places to look is the [IATA Travel Center.](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm)  It will ask you for information about your trip, its duration, and your passport status, along with any transit countries involved.  Once you enter in this information, you will be provided with a list of health & immigration documents you will need for your flight.

Trying it out for an Indian national traveling from Hungary to India via Ukraine, with random data inserted for things like "duration of stay" and "passport expiry date", I found the following advice:

> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers transiting through Kiev: Boryspil (KBP) or Zhuliany (IEV) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So it seems that you will be OK in Ukraine, but you should go to the site and enter the correct information for your own situation to be sure.